# Doctrine mapping dont working properly

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine, mapping

I'm having problems with doctrine mapped superclass.
When I execute the symfony command:

```
php app/console doctrine:mapping:info
```

I receive this exception message:

```
[Doctrine\Common\Persistence\Mapping\MappingException]
Class 'DBiagi\EitaBundle\Entity\BaseFoo' does not exist
```

The strange part is that the BaseFoo class is not in the Entity folder, and this class is a mapped superclass.
Here is my files:

```
<?php    
# src/DBiagi/EitaBundle/Model/BaseFoo.php

namespace DBiagi\EitaBundle\Model;

/**
 * Description of BaseFoo
 *
 */
abstract class BaseFoo implements BaseFooInterface{

    private $id;
    private $name;

    public function getId(){
        return $this->id;
    }

    public function getName(){
        return $this->name;
    }
}
```

The mapping definition:

```
# src/DBiagi/EitaBundle/Resources/doctrine/BaseFoo.orm.yml
DBiagi\EitaBundle\Model\BaseFoo:
    type: mappedSuperclass
    fields:
        id:
            id:
                type: integer
                id: true
                generator:
                    strategy: AUTO
        name:
            type: string
            length: 255
```

Note that the class DBiagi\EitaBundle\Entity\BaseFoo doesn't exist in fact and the BaseFoo class lives in the Model folder, so the question is: Why doctrine is trying to load this class? I cant get my entities mapped because of this exception.
A help will be very appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should set correct namespace for entities of your bundle in main app config. Suppose you use yml config, smth like:

```
orm:
    entity_managers:
        default:
            mappings:
                DBiagiEitaBundle:
                    prefix: DBiagi\EitaBundle\Model
```

Comment: Thanks to point me in the right direction. In the doctrine section of the [symfony documentation](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/configuration/doctrine.html) there is a tutorial showing how to change the default entity folder. Thats solved my problem. Thanks.